# How to allow PHP file read parameter passed in a clean way using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've been trying fix my error, first here is my `.htaccess` code:

```
# Clean Url for User Profiles
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+friend\.php\?user_name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ friend/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^friend/([^/]+)/?$ friend.php?user_name=$1 [L,QSA]
# End Clean Url Htaccess
```

My intentions with this code is to make this URL http://localhost:8888/circlepanda/friend?user_name=kendrick

Display like this http://localhost:8888/circlepanda/friend/kendrick and work.
The page opens good, burr the parameter isn't parsed. How do I fix this?

Comment: There is a difference between `/friend` and `/friend.php`...

Comment: The issue probably is here: `^ friend`. Remove that strange blank character in there.

Comment: I would appreciate if you point out clearly what you mean @arkascha

Comment: Or what do you actually mean by "but the parameter isn't parsed"?

Comment: I doubt I can get more "clearly" than what I wrote. I pointed out two obvious issues with your rule set that should get fixed.

Comment: I echoed the parameter and what i see is kendrick.php

Comment: Also there appears to be some issue in the RewriteCond... that `+` in there makes no sense: `^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+friend\.php`, not does the `\s` in there. And `[A-Z]{3,}` certainly will _not_ match `circlepanda`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148464/discussion-between-precious-aniefiok-and-arkascha).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code. I tried to fix what I see, here is my version of what you probably are trying to implement:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# external: /..../friend?username=joe >> /..../friend/joe
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} user_name=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^friend/?$ friend/%1 [R=301,QSA]

# internal: /friend/joe >> friend.php?user_name=joe
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^friend/([^/]+)/?$ friend.php?user_name=$1 [END,QSA]
```

Depending on your specific situation it might be that you need to add a `RewriteBase`. See the official documentation for that.

If you experience an internal server error using above lines chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. In that case you need to replace the `[END]` flag with the `[L]` flag.

---

And a general hint: you should always prefer to place such rules inside the http servers (virtual) host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (`.htaccess` style files). Those files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they really slow down the server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have control over the host configuration (read: really cheap hosting service providers) or if you have an application that relies on writing its own rewrite rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thanks you're not wrong at all, burr with this code above my previous code

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Nothing worked... Pulled it below the above code and err thing started working... Thanks...